# Build lookup for getting a single value based on multiple static parameters

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Let following be the data set:

```
- ref: UNIQUE_VAL_1
  PCids: [ TTT ]
  LCids: [ TTT ]
  SCids: [ TTT ]
  PIEs: [ PIE_1 ]
  case: [ ACC ]


- ref: UNIQUE_VAL_2
  PCids: [ CCC ]
  LCids: [ CCC ]
  SCids: [ CCC ]
  PIEs: [ PIE_2 ]
  case: [ ACC ]


- ref: UNIQUE_VAL_3
  PCids: [ DDD ]
  SCids: [ PPP ]
  LCids: [ PPP ]
  PIEs: [ PIE_3 ]
  case: [ ACC ]
```

For each combination of values of PCids, SCids, LCids, PIEs and case,
there will be a unique ref value.

```
Eg Input:
  PCids = DDD
  SCids = PPP
  LCids = PPP
  PIEs = PIE_3
  case = ACC

  Output:
  ref = UNIQUE_VAL_3
```

How can we realise this in code ? I am trying to think of a solution where I am not forced to write a huge if-else ladder.

Tried following solution:
Create an md5 of all the dependant parameters and put it as a key with value as the ref in a hashmap.

Caveat:
Will have to use an initialiser code which will run before everything else always to create a hashmap in memory.

Comment: How many distinct values can you have for PCids? For SCids, LCids, PIEs, and case? If it's a reasonable number, you could bitmap the individual properties and pack them into a 32-bit or 64-bit integer.

Comment: The number of distinct values can grow over time based on the business logic.

Comment: It can grow over time, but how large? You have four categories: PCids, SCids, LCids, PIEs. Assuming you have fewer than 256 values in each category, you can assign each value within a category a unique number and then pack the four values into a 32-bit integer. If you have fewer than 65,536 values in each category, you can pack them into a 64-bit integer. If your problem fits into those confines, I can provide more detail.